# Cycles Glass BSDF on a Diamond viewport problem

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, glass

I've got an issue with my glass viewport render.
It creates some kind of a hole in that object, which looks bad. In comparison to the tutorial, with simplest nodes and everything super basic, with the same render and light paths settings, it's just totally unlike.
Of course the shape is a little bit different, but I guess it shouldn't look like that anyways..
Do you please have any ideas how to fix that?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your first screenshot show the world shader.  Can you switch to Object and show the shader you're using on the diamond?  Also, check to see if all of your face normals are facing outward.  If possible, add your blend file to your question.

Comment: thanks @MartyFouts , I just updated this and here's how it looks. Simplest glass shader, the same as in the tutorial

Comment: Then I would look for differences in your lighting set up and whether or not your diamond has topology problems.  Also, did the tutorial make any changes to default rendering parameters.  This is often done when transparent objects are added to scenes.

Comment: Looks like it might be about topology.. Don't know what exactly, but it looks much better on some pre made diamond I placed with the extra add-on.

Comment: for what it is worth, about 1/2 of all topo problems can be solved by going into edit mode, selecting all, merge by distance, recalculate normals.

Comment: @MartyFouts that's super helpful. thanks a lot !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From my experience in Blender, a more complex diamond mesh gives the light more directions to scatter, which will increase the number of refraction effects you can detect on the surface.

In jeweler's terms, the *cut* of the diamond influences the *clarity*, *sparkle*, and *brilliance*.  Sometimes these are at odds with each other.

[image]

Also, increasing the number of *Glossy* and *Total* bounces under *Light Paths* will fill these dark areas with more refractions.

[image]